# PyQt6 mouseMoveEvent fires crazy when dragging left and right

Tags: pyqt5, pyqt6

i have a mouse move event build in PyQt6, but the problem is, that when I move my rectangle, it is moving spontaneously from left to right.

Here you have a example of my code:

```
class GanttItem(QGraphicsItem):
def __init__(self, start, duration, name, color, parent=None):
    super().__init__(parent)
    self.start = start
    self.duration = duration
    self.name = name
    self.color = color
    self.dragging = False

def boundingRect(self):
    return QRectF(0, 0, self.duration * 30, 50)

def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
    painter.setBrush(QBrush(self.color))
    painter.drawRect(self.boundingRect())
    painter.drawText(self.boundingRect(), Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter, self.name)

def mousePressEvent(self, event: QMouseEvent):
    self.dragging = True
    self.mouse_press_pos = event.pos()

def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event: QMouseEvent):
    self.dragging = False

def mouseMoveEvent(self, event: QMouseEvent):
    if self.dragging:

        event_x = event.pos().x()

        print(event_x)

        self.setPos(event_x, self.pos().y())
```

[image: Demo]

And due to the print, I get these e.g. console outputs:

```
332.0
-212.0
331.0
-213.0
90.0
-210.0
```

so u can see that the cursor jumps randomly from 332.0 points to -212.0 points.
Has anyone else experienced that? I think that the MouseEvent is fired multiple times, but i can not verify how to filter them.

Comment: When an item is the "mouse grabber" and is moved in the meantime, it receives mouse movements caused by the new position, which is obvious if you think about it: to the point of view of the item, the mouse has a new position. So, those values are not random, they are exactly the difference between the different position and the original mouse cursor. Note that QGraphicsItem natively support mouse movement via the `ItemIsMovable` flag, if you want to prevent vertical shifting you should properly implement it through `itemChange()`.